# Quitting pygame without quitting idle

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, exit

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

displayHeight = 600
displayWidth = 800

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth,displayHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pythoral Reef')

green = (0, 100, 0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (39, 64, 139)
black = (0,0,0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
img = pygame.image.load('coral reef.jpg')

play = False
instructions = False
done = False

def checkClick():
    global instructions, play, done
    if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] > 50 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < 250 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] > 400 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < 500:
        instructions = True
    elif pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] > 300 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < 500 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] > 400 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < 500:
        play = True
    elif pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] > 550 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < 750 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] > 400 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < 500:
        done = True

def evalOption():
    global instructions, play, done, gameExit
    if instructions == True:
        print 'instructions'
        instructions = False

    elif play == True:
        pygame.display.quit()

    elif done == True:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

def textObjects(text, font, color):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def messageDisplay(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 90)
    TextSurf, TextRect = textObjects(text, largeText, blue)    
    TextRect.center = ((displayWidth/2, displayHeight/4))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def optionsDisplay(x, text, size):
    smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', size)
    TextSurf, TextRect = textObjects(text, smallText, white)    
    TextRect.center = ((x, 450))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def nameDisplay(x, y, text):
    smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 35)
    TextSurf, TextRect = textObjects(text, smallText, green)    
    TextRect.center = ((x, y))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def rectangle(color, x, y):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [x, y, 200, 100])


def menu():
    gameExit = False
    if gameExit == False:
        gameDisplay.blit(img, [0, 0])
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    checkClick()
                    evalOption()

        messageDisplay('PYTHORAL REEF')
        rectangle(black, 50, 400)
        rectangle(black, 300, 400)
        rectangle(black, 550, 400)
        optionsDisplay(150, 'INSTRUCTIONS', 22)
        optionsDisplay(400, 'PLAY', 35)
        optionsDisplay(650, 'QUIT', 35)
        nameDisplay(displayWidth/2, 260, 'NICK MONTELEONE')
        nameDisplay(displayWidth/2, 225, 'BY')
        nameDisplay(displayWidth/2, 295, '2015')
        pygame.display.update

menu()
pygame.quit()
```

This is my code for a menu screen for a text adventure game that I am making. I wanted to use this as the menu screen so when you click play it will exit out of pygame and return to the python shell to run the game. However, when I quit in the function evalOption() by clicking on play, it will print error: font not initialized as if the program is still trying to run. Does anyone know how to fix this so that I can quit out of pygame, but still run a module in python. This program will eventually be imported into my real text adventure module. Here is the link to the coral reef background if needed: https://www.google.com/search?q=coral+reef&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=799&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix_OmD7s_JAhXGWD4KHXW-CrsQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=_dFX3xqK97FGNM%3A

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The error actually is 'error: display Surface quit' not font not initialized, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because your code tries to draw to the screen after you called `pygame.quit()`.

Instead of

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_x:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
```

just use

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_x:
        return
```

to exit your mainloop.